# passing item_number to a hosted button

Tags: paypal

I have a small, simple, website on which I offer 40 different items with the same pricing structure.  I have created a hosted paypal add-to-cart button with that pricing structure, and a dummy "Item Name" and "Item ID".

I then generate an html page for each item that contains a form reference to the hosted button, but adds hidden variables passing the item_name and item_number of the individual item.

The passed item_name variable successfully overwrites the dummy 'item name' from the hosted button when appearing in the paypal shopping cart, but the passed item_number variable does not overwrite the dummy 'item id' in the button.  I do not see an item_id variable in the HTML Variables documentation.

It seems logical that I should be able to overwrite 'item id' if I can overwrite 'item_name', but if the item_number variable doesn't do it, what does?

Answer (score 0):

When using hosted buttons, some variables are allowed to be over written while others are not as you can see with what you are doing.  Your options would be to either use a non hosted clear text button where you over write any of the options you want to on your page or use the Button Manager API's to generate a hosted or encrypted button on the fly.  This would then allow you to pass over what ever variables you want, and you would get the hosted or encrypted code back in your response that you would then display on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Button API and adding the item_number var when creating the hosted button doesn't work either, it creates a hosted button with `item_number = 0` if you use `BMCreateButtonResponseType` Submit method only from paypal samples.

In order to get the item_number you need to set inventory, by using

```
BMSetInventoryRequestType request = new BMSetInventoryRequestType(); 
request.ItemTrackingDetails.ItemNumber = ItemNumber;
```